# Installing a customizing theme

Tags: themes

I use virtualbox to use ubuntu (12.04). I want to customize the theme but I didn't find in the preferences how to that. So I webt to ubuntu-art, and I downloaded a .sh file (metacity theme), but how do I install this file ? is it a package ?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .sh file is a shell script, in other words it's an executable. You can run it by either making it executable

```
chmod a+x file.sh
./file.sh
```

or running it with bash:

```
bash file.sh
```

P.S. I do not guarantee that the downloaded executable will not break your configuration,  destroy your system, kill your cat and cause an apocalypse. Beware! MyUnity might be a better solution, although I have had problems with that one as well.

Comment: Sorry, I used the trick, but here's what I get : Segmentation fault (core dumped), and I am told the applciation Zenity closed unexpectedly. Do you have an idea of how to fix it ?

Comment: Not really - I think that either the theme or the package might be damaged. Zenity is just a simple program for making dialogs from a shell script, you can test that it works by running `zenity --info --text="Hello world"`

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (Ctrl + ALt + T) and type `sudo apt-get install myunity`. Press y, then when it is done, type `myunity`.Go to the themes tab, clcik the theme you want to apply and click OK. You can also install themes from this tab.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it